# Gradle project that the dependencies cannot be imported or even not be existed at all

Tags: gradle

I create a simple Gradle project, then add some dependencies for test, it can build the project normally, but **CANNOT** use the APIs in class, the `gradle.build` file:

```
plugins {
    id('java')
id('war')
}
repositories { mavenLocal() mavenCentral() }
// ... other code
dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2'
}
```

By the way, it's an old-test Java project, in class file I cannot import the packages like this: `import javax.servlet.*;`, how to solve? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It's so weird, it works today, when I open the project, the all needed libraries appear in the External Libraries, and I can import the classes now.

Why? I already restarted the IDEA and project several times yesterday, but that did not work at all, however, it's automatically solved today.